# Why does my PWM signal go high when my sinusoid is decreasing and vice versa?

Tags: pwm, control-system

I am using hysteresis control on a three phase inverter, but for some reason when my PWM goes high, the power decreases? It is opposite of what I would expect. Does anyone have a clue on what is going on?

I have a picture of one phase included:

[image]

Comment: Can you highlight specifically which part of that waveform concerns you, and also tell us what the yellow & purple channels are measuring?

Comment: Yeah! So at the top of the sine "waves" the PWM signal is full on, which i think should mean that the current would increase, but it starts to decrease :/ - The yellow and Purple channes are my reference current and my grid current. Using hysteresis methode subtracts them and gives out a signal that can be used to either make i PWM go high or low thus creasing a new sine wave for the grid. Hope my answer makes sense

Comment: I think you mean [sinusoid](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sinusoid) instead of [sinus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sinus).

Comment: I strongly suspect that your PWM signal is not actually "full on" as much as you think it is. I think it's likely that if you zoomed in closer to that section that it is still actually alternating between high & low, but the low periods are not being sampled often enough for you to see in this 'zoomed out' snapshot.

Comment: Hmm, no they are actually full on and when the wave is at full negative its full OFF! Which is what i dont get... It should be opposite i feel like... Its for the 6 switches on my inverter

Comment: You say that your *current* starts decreasing at maximum PWM and maximum *voltage*. This would be expected for a reactive load, although that would seem to be capacitive, where current leads voltage.

Comment: Right now i have a LCL filter at the output of my inverter! But i just dont understand why the current and voltage decrease when i have a PWM signal thats ON